# Ansible how to correctly specify socket value when resetting Mysql password on Raspian

Tags: mysql, ansible

I'm trying to run a simple server set up on a Raspberry Pi but I'm running issues with the Mysql module and resetting the root password. I'm using code that I've see used in several tutorials for setting up Mysql

```
- name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
  become: true
  mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_pass }} login_unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  with_items:
   - 127.0.0.1
   - ::1
```

The error I get is this `"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "127.0.0.1", "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)\"`

I understand this has to do with how Mysql connects the root user the first time without a password, but I'm not sure how to specify the socket correctly for the first time connection.

Comment: There is no problem with your socket. The error message is crystal clear: `unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /root/.my.cnf has the credentials`. Set the correct credentials in the module or in the config file. The current root@localhost password is not empty.

Comment: so, Mysql is just installed, there is no password. From what I've read I need to specify the socket for the first connection but I don't know where to do that correctly.

Comment: You already did set the socket and there is absolutely no problem with that. Now you need to understand why you think there is no password for root@localhost (`'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`) and why ansible/mysql is telling you the exact opposite (`Access denied`). Note the problem could also be that this used does not exist at all. You might want to try to login as `root@127.0.0.1`. This question is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here. You should gather as much debug info as possible before heading to https://superuser.com

Comment: I assume there is no password because the playbook is installing Mysql for the first time on the device and I didn't set it. If I were doing this manually, I'd run the secure installation, flush the pw's, and then set the password. I'm asking about specifying the socket because that's how I read you're supposed to first connect as passwordless root

Comment: You **DID** set the socket, the module is using it to connect, **IT WORKS**. A socket is just an "address" to connect to your server. It does not bypass authentication. Don't "assume" a user exists and/or has an empty password, test it and give an evidence. Your error message indicates `root@localhost` either does not exist or has a (preconfigured) non-empty password. You can continue to think it is not the case if you wish but from experience, the machine usually wins at this kind of game.

Comment: So, my question is about doing this the right way. I get the same error without specifying the socket. As above, if the password is set, I didn't do it. What I've read from anyone having this issue is that its the socket, and my assumption has been that I am doing that incorrectly. Logging in and specifying the password defeats the point of idempotency. I'm clearly not articulating the question correctly, but I appreciate your help in trying to resolve this. I could theoretically write the pw I want into the my.cnf file a step earlier, but it seems like a work around for how it should work